# WPF customControl and template inheritance

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, templates, custom-controls

I have a little trouble to find how to proceed for my ImageButton template.

To do simple : I have created a new customControl ImageButton, by following this tutorial : http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/773386/WPF-ImageButton

So far, so good, works great.

But, on my application, I have different possible theme for button (known at application start). And my different button theme are defined this way :

```
<Style x:Key="MONDE0_ImageActionButton" TargetType="Button">

    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Border Name="BaseBorder" CornerRadius="5" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black" Background="{DynamicResource DefaultBlueButton}">
                    <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,2,0">

                    </ContentPresenter>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="BaseBorder" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource DefaultOverBlueButton}" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="Button.IsPressed" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="BaseBorder" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource DefaultClickedBlueButton}" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>

            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

The problem is, when I try to apply this theme to my imgButton by doing this :

```
<VegaCtr:ImageButton x:Name="btn_Send" Margin="5" Style="{DynamicResource MONDE0_actionButton}" Width="105" Height="40" ToolTip="Envoyer" Command="{Binding SendCommand}"
            Image="pack://application:,,,/Vega_WPF_Themes;component/Themes/Common/Images/Yes.png" Content="Valider"/>
```

My imagebutton style

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:ImageButton}" x:Name="StyleImgButton">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:ImageButton}">
                <!-- Button Content -->
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                    <Image Source="{TemplateBinding Image}" Visibility="{TemplateBinding Image, Converter={StaticResource VisibilityConvertor}}"
                             Width="{TemplateBinding ImageWidth}" Height="{TemplateBinding ImageHeight}" Margin="0,0,5,0" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" Style="{StaticResource buttonLabel}" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                </StackPanel>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

The base template for imageButton doesn't works. And when I delete the style attribute, it works ... So, my question is, how can I make this works ? I need to have base imageButton template and possibly add my other style (with triggers; etc...).
Is this possible ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

use basedOn attribute on your style to set base style

```
<Style x:Key="MONDE0_ImageActionButton" TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource "My_BaseStyle"}>
```

Comment: It wont works because style of ImageButton target an ImageButton which is inheritance of Button. I add my StyleImgButton style to be more clear (very close to the one on codeproject)